# Capistrano deployment to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, migration, capistrano

I've managed to sucessfully set up a server with auto deployment, luckly and finally.

Now there's one tiny issue that happens when I deploy...

When the deployment happen, the database gets migrated, thing is that even after the restart of the server the database keeps kind of "cached", and does not recognize any of the changes made by the migration until I go to the server and restart the mysql service.

Any thoughts on how to work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

This is an example migration;

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :string, default: 'member'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

But how do you know that the changes are not recognized? Can you post some example?
In production environment Rails are able to cache some DB replies but restart of rails server should clear all those caches. So it seems that the problem is somewhere in mysql part (personally I'm only using Postgres so don't know much about mysql). Maybe the solution is to add some mysql restart commands to Capistrano task?
In Capistrano 3.1 it would be something like (asuming you are runing linux server):

```
task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
       execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
       execute "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart"
    end
  end
```

Comment: The only bad thing about this is that it will have to run a sudo command and ill have to configure this user to not get prompted for password when running sudo which imo is a bit unsafe, but thanks, also, the example migration will be on the main post (which ill edit in a bit)